# Removing face details with Movie-Clip-Editor

Tags: masking

I try to use blender for removing (e.g.) eyebrows from a face in a video clip.

I did some practice and came along with this procedure:

1. Add tracking-points to face
2. Mask the area that I want to remove, in this case one eyebrow for
   test
3. Linking the mask to the tracking point
4. Start to play the video and adjust the mask to still cover the area, while face is moving. Red Button "Automatic keyframe insertion" is enabled for this process
5. Use the node editor to use "Distort => Translate" on the mask and create set Y-value to -2.XXX to fill the mask with the skin color above the eyebrow. Attaching a blur-filter and I'm finished.

Do you know some more efficient techniques ? Maybe one to cover the hole face at once with the skin color ?

At the moment I'm trying to add tracking points to the video clip, to use them in the 3D-View. In the final step I would try to add a mask that attaches itself to the 3D-View in face area.

It's all like searching for Gimp's clone-tool, just for a video.

Ty

Comment: Nope thats about the most straight forward way, its what I do at work for a quick fix

Comment: Ok, ty for replying.